ggplot2 with 2 panels with a log scale on only 1
I want to plot Gross Domestic Product per capita (gdppc) and growthRate = diff(log(gdppc)) in 2 panels with gdppc on a log scale and growthRate on a linear scale.
EXAMPLE:
set.seed(1)
growthRate <- rnorm(100, 1)
Y <- exp(cumsum(growthRate))
DF <- data.frame(year=seq(1901, 2000), growthRate, Y)

DFlong <- pivot_longer(DF, -1)

plot0 <- ggplot(DFlong, 
    aes(x = year, y = value))
(plot1 <- (plot0 + geom_line() + 
    facet_grid(rows = vars(name), scales='free')))

(plot2 <- plot1 + scale_y_continuous(trans='log10'))

How can I apply trans='log10' to only the "Y" panel
and not 'growthRate'?

The ggh4x package is the easiest way I've encountered:
ggplot(DFlong, aes(x = year, y = value)) +
  geom_line() + 
  facet_grid(rows = vars(name), scales='free') +
  ggh4x::facetted_pos_scales(y = list(
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(scale = 1)),
    scale_y_continuous(trans='log10',
                       labels = scales::label_scientific())
  ))


If you want even more flexibility, at the cost of more code, you could use patchwork to combine and align two plots. Here, I've arbitrarily made the two facets different sizes.
library(patchwork); library(dplyr)
(ggplot(DFlong |> filter(name == first(name)), 
       aes(x = year, y = value)) +
  geom_line() + 
  facet_grid(rows = vars(name), scales='free') +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(scale = 1)) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank())) /
  
(ggplot(DFlong |> filter(name == last(name)), 
       aes(x = year, y = value)) +
  geom_line() + 
  facet_grid(rows = vars(name), scales='free') +
  scale_y_continuous(trans='log10',
                       labels = scales::label_scientific())) +
  plot_layout(height = c(3,1), axes = "collect")



That's great. Thanks very much!!! Spencer Graves
